# My actionlistener is not working on my multi-class/frame Java project, can anyone help me fix it?

Tags: java

Alright, so I am trying to get values picked out with radio buttons and a confirm button that exits you out of the screen, but my actionlistener is not working. Keep in mind, I have only been programming on Java for less than 5 months and only finishing up the basics. Here is my code below:

```
    import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Processor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {  

String processor;
int processorValue;
int intelCorei3Value = 100;
int AMDRyzen3Value = 100;
int intelCorei5Value = 200;
int AMDRyzen5Value = 200;
int intelCorei7Value = 300;
int AMDRyzen7Value = 300;

JPanel processorPanel;
ImageIcon intelCorei3Image, AMDRyzen3Image, intelCorei5Image, AMDRyzen5Image, intelCorei7Image, AMDRyzen7Image;
JLabel chooseYourProcessorLabel, intelCorei3Label, AMDRyzen3Label, intelCorei5Label, AMDRyzen5Label, intelCorei7Label, AMDRyzen7Label;
JButton confirmButton;
JRadioButton intelCorei3Button, AMDRyzen3Button, intelCorei5Button, AMDRyzen5Button, intelCorei7Button, AMDRyzen7Button; 

public Processor() {

JFrame GUI3 = new JFrame();
GUI3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
GUI3.setSize(700, 500); 
GUI3.setVisible(true); 

GUI3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel processorPanel = new JPanel();
processorPanel.setSize(700, 800);
processorPanel.setLocation(0, 75);
processorPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(processorPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 800));

ImageIcon intelCorei3Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Intel Core i3.png"));
JLabel intelCorei3Label = new JLabel(intelCorei3Image);
intelCorei3Label.setSize(100, 100);

ImageIcon AMDRyzen3Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("AMD Ryzen 3.png"));
JLabel AMDRyzen3Label = new JLabel(AMDRyzen3Image);
AMDRyzen3Label.setSize(100, 100);

ImageIcon intelCorei5Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Intel Core i5.png"));
JLabel intelCorei5Label = new JLabel(intelCorei5Image);
intelCorei5Label.setSize(100, 100);

ImageIcon AMDRyzen5Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("AMD Ryzen 5.png"));
JLabel AMDRyzen5Label = new JLabel(AMDRyzen5Image);
AMDRyzen5Label.setSize(100, 100);

ImageIcon intelCorei7Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Intel Core i7.png"));
JLabel intelCorei7Label = new JLabel(intelCorei7Image);
intelCorei7Label.setSize(100, 100);

ImageIcon AMDRyzen7Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("AMD Ryzen 7.png"));
JLabel AMDRyzen7Label = new JLabel(AMDRyzen7Image);
AMDRyzen7Label.setSize(100, 100);

JLabel chooseYourProcessorLabel = new JLabel("Select a processor for your computer build!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
chooseYourProcessorLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24)); 
chooseYourProcessorLabel.setSize(700, 100); 
chooseYourProcessorLabel.setLocation(0, 0);

JButton confirmButton = new JButton("CONFIRM");
confirmButton.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48)); 
confirmButton.setSize(700, 100);
confirmButton.setLocation(0, 375);
confirmButton.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton intelCorei3Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i3 ($" + intelCorei3Value + ")");
intelCorei3Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
intelCorei3Button.setSize(100, 100); 
intelCorei3Button.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton AMDRyzen3Button = new JRadioButton("AMD Ryzen 3 ($" + AMDRyzen3Value + ")");
AMDRyzen3Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
AMDRyzen3Button.setSize(100, 100);
AMDRyzen3Button.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton intelCorei5Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i5 ($" + intelCorei5Value + ")");
intelCorei5Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
intelCorei5Button.setSize(100, 100);
intelCorei5Button.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton AMDRyzen5Button = new JRadioButton("AMD Ryzen 5 ($" + AMDRyzen5Value + ")");
AMDRyzen5Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
AMDRyzen5Button.setSize(100, 100);
AMDRyzen5Button.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton intelCorei7Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i7 ($" + intelCorei7Value + ")");
intelCorei7Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
intelCorei7Button.setSize(100, 100); 
intelCorei7Button.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton AMDRyzen7Button = new JRadioButton("AMD Ryzen 7 ($" + AMDRyzen7Value + ")");
AMDRyzen7Button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32)); 
AMDRyzen7Button.setSize(100, 100); 
AMDRyzen7Button.addActionListener(this);

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(intelCorei3Button);
group.add(AMDRyzen3Button);
group.add(intelCorei5Button);
group.add(AMDRyzen5Button);
group.add(intelCorei7Button);
group.add(AMDRyzen7Button);

processorPanel.add(intelCorei3Button);
processorPanel.add(intelCorei3Label);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen3Button);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen3Label);
processorPanel.add(intelCorei5Button);
processorPanel.add(intelCorei5Label);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen5Button);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen5Label);
processorPanel.add(intelCorei7Button);
processorPanel.add(intelCorei7Label);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen7Button);
processorPanel.add(AMDRyzen7Label);

GUI3.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
GUI3.add(chooseYourProcessorLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
GUI3.add(confirmButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
} 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) { 

if(click.getSource() == confirmButton) {
    System.out.println("SUP");
}

else if(click.getSource() == intelCorei3Button) {
processor = "Intel Core i3";
processorValue = intelCorei3Value;
}

else if(click.getSource() == AMDRyzen3Button) {
processor = "AMD Ryzen 3";
processorValue = AMDRyzen3Value;
}

else if(click.getSource() == intelCorei5Button) {
processor = "Intel Core i5";
processorValue = intelCorei5Value;
}

else if(click.getSource() == AMDRyzen5Button) {
processor = "AMD Ryzen 5";
processorValue = AMDRyzen5Value;
}

else if(click.getSource() == intelCorei7Button) {
processor = "Intel Core i7";
processorValue = intelCorei7Value;
}

else if(click.getSource() == AMDRyzen7Button) {
processor = "AMD Ryzen 7";
processorValue = AMDRyzen7Value;
}

}
}
```

Remember, this is a multi-window/multi-class Java project, with two previous classes also using actionlisteners that both work, if you need to see those tell me.

Comment: BTW, the "confirmButton" is supposed to dispose of the current frame, GUI3.

Comment: Your shadowing your button variables, redeclaring them in a local context to `Processor`, so the instance fields are likely still `null`

Comment: Can you explain that, I am very new, sorry.

Comment: i highly recommend looking up java coding conventions... you shouldn't declare multiple variables on 1 line. it makes the code unreadable. but there's many other conventions that would help you. what MadProgrammer says is true but if you change your constructor so that instead of redeclaring the variables you reuse the member variable like this: intelCorei5Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i5 ($" + intelCorei5Value + ")"); for your different JRadio buttons, it would remove the shadowing issue.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is, you're shadowing your variables.  That is, you've decleared your buttons as instance fields...

```
JRadioButton intelCorei3Button, AMDRyzen3Button, intelCorei5Button, AMDRyzen5Button, intelCorei7Button, AMDRyzen7Button;
```

But then in the constructor, you've declared them again, this time in a local context to the constructor...

```
public Processor() {
    //...
    JRadioButton intelCorei3Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i3 ($" + intelCorei3Value + ")");
```

This means that the instance fields are `null`, so when `actionPerformed` is called, you're effectively doing...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {

    if (click.getSource() == null) {
```

which is, obviously, pointless.

Start by removing the redeclaration of the buttons from the constructor

```
public Processor() {
    //...
    intelCorei3Button = new JRadioButton("Intel Core i3 ($" + intelCorei3Value + ")");
```